# How to rename a file after upload

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

I have to upload file using Ftp protocol on server, and rename uploaded file after uploading.

I can upload it, but don't know how to rename it.

Code looks like this:

```
FtpWebRequest requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + "httpdocs/webroot/" + destination + "/" + fileName));
requestFTP.Proxy = null;

requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
FileStream fStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();
int bufferLength = 2048;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
Stream uploadStream = requestFTP.GetRequestStream();
int contentLength = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
while (contentLength != 0)
{
  uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
  contentLength = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
}
uploadStream.Close();
fStream.Close();

requestFTP = null;

string newFilename = fileName.Replace(".ftp", "");
requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename; // this like makes a problem
requestFTP.RenameTo(newFilename);
```

Error I'm getting is

> Error 2   Non-invocable member 'System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RenameTo'
>   cannot be used like a method.

Comment: both `Method` and `Rename` are `string`s. They are not functions.

Comment: C# doesn't provide a direct rename method. You should copy the file with a new name in the server and delete the old file.

Answer (score 13):

RenameTo is a property, not a method. Your code should read:

```
// requestFTP has been set to null in the previous line
requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + "httpdocs/webroot/" + destination + "/" + fileName));
requestFTP.Proxy = null;
requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);

string newFilename = fileName.Replace(".ftp", "");
requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
requestFTP.RenameTo = newFilename;
requestFTP.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just upload it with the correct filename in stead? Change your first line with the filename you actually want.

```
FtpWebRequest requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + "httpdocs/webroot/" + destination + "/" + newFileName));
```

But do open the reading stream from your old filename.

Comment: Typically this approach is used to signify to polling applications that the file has finished uploading. The joys of FTP.

Comment: Tnx, but I really need to copy file with some tmp name, and after that to rename it to it's native name.

Comment: Why not just answer the OP instead?