# Renaming file with FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

When moving a file to another FTP location you must use `RenameTo` with the new FTP location.

In this example how do you use `RenameTo` to move to the new FTP location?

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
try
{
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mysite.com/folder1/fileName.ext");
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
    ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
    ftpRequest.RenameTo = "ftp://mysite.com/folder2/fileName.ext";
    ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    ftpResponse.Close();
    ftpRequest = null;
}
catch (Exception ex) { Label1.Text = (ex.ToString()); }
```

Comment: This post on a similar topic may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13026170/4072843

Answer (score 7):

Set a target path to `.RenameTo` property, not URL:

```
ftpRequest.RenameTo = "/folder2/fileName.ext";
```

As per MSDN documentation for [`FtpWebRequest.RenameTo` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.renameto):

> Gets or sets the **new name** of a file being renamed.

Compare to [`WebRequest.Create` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create#system-net-webrequest-create(system-string)):

> Initializes a new WebRequest instance for the specified **URI scheme**.

---

The URL would be redundant in `RenameTo`, as you cannot use it to "rename" the file to another server.

Answer (score -1):

A-
change it to be

ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mysite.com//folder1/fileName.ext");

B-
ftpRequest.RenameTo = "ftp://mysite.com//folder2/fileName.ext";

Just add (/) before your file folder that allow you to delFile,renFile also downLoadFile

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thank you for your answer. Please remember that a lot of users are not native english speakers, so abreviations like delFile will not be so obvious to them.