# C# How to Rename file after File.Copy without using File.Move

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I'm Working on a module where I need to copy a file to FTP path using C#. From there FTP will start processing that file based on name and extension. My Problem is while copying a huge file to the path FTP Picked up that file for processing before copying process get completed. To overcome this issue I changed the file name and extension and done with the file copy.

Now I need to rename the file with Original name. Is there any way in C# to rename the file without using File.Move ?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use `File.Move`?

Comment: If you are working with a remote FTP site then look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638532/renaming-file-with-ftpwebrequest

Comment: @Steve, I *think* he's saying that he has a local directory that some FTP process checks for files to upload, and he doesn't want that process to start sending a file that's in the middle of being copied to the local FTP directory, so he wants to copy the file to that directory by a different name and switch the filename at the last minute so it's fully "there" before the FTP uploading process notices it.

Comment: @adv12 possible, hope for some clarifications

Comment: `File.Move` calls the WinAPI `MoveFile` function, which is about as low-level as you need to go. What's the issue with using it? *I'm a carpenter. Can I pound these nails into a board without using a hammer or nailgun?* Sure you can, but it's not going to be as easy or efficient.

Comment: @adv12: Yes, that's exactly what's being asked, and File.Move will do it instantly if they're on the same volume (it just changes the file system info and doesn't actually move any data). You can't get any quicker than that, even with very large files.

Comment: Sounds like the process picking up the file, is picking up the file to early. Do you have any control over the pickup process? Here we often use "end of transmission files". In the sense that, a customer would upload their large file(s) to our servers, once done they upload the "end of transmission file", and our pickup process triggers on the arrival of the "end of transmission" file.

Comment: @Steve, Thanks for your reply, I'm not using FTPWebRequest instead moving the file to windows shared folder.

Comment: @adv12, Thanks for our reply. Yeah process picking up the huge file before the copying process get completed. Due to that it's breaking the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you´ll have to use File.Move to accomplish this task. It is the easier approach.

If, for whatever reason you don´t want to use it, you can do it this way (you will have to reference Microsoft.VisualBasic):

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile(myfile, newName);
```

Comment: It is quite unclear. If OP confirm your theory i ll delete