# Rename directory on FTP server using FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to rename a folder on my FTP server that contains n files.

My approach, after checking if the directory is existing, was:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(ftpDirectory);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
request.Credentials = credentials;
request.RenameTo = folderNameThen;
```

The variable `ftpDirectory` contains the whole address to the directory:

```
string ftpDirectory = "ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + folderToRename + "/";
```

But I got an exception:

> The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.

But I couldn't image how the path should look like to rename the folder if mine isn't correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026170/how-to-rename-a-file-after-upload

Comment: @UweKeim It's not the same actually. And he has used `RenameTo` as a property as well. @Zumarta I think you have that extra `/` in `ftpDirectory` :)

Comment: Actually that simple, wow. Didn't think about that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
string ftpDirectory = "ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + folderToRename + "/";
```

to

```
string ftpDirectory = "ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + folderToRename;
```

:)