# Moving file using FTP in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ftp

Currently my app's FTP upload part looks like below. What I need to do is, to upload file with `target_file_tmp_name` and when upload finishes to move it (or rename) to `target_file_name`. Can't figure out how to wait for upload to finish and then rename remote file.

Any suggestions?

```
var result_file_name = root_dir + "\\" + file_name + ".eps";
System.Uri target_file_name = new Uri(ftp_path + "/" + file_name + ".eps");
System.Uri target_file_tmp_name = new Uri(ftp_path + "/" + file_name + ".tmp");

await WhenFileCreated(result_file_name);
if (File.Exists(result_file_name))
{
    SetProgressText("Uploading to server...");
    WebClient wc_uploader = new WebClient();

    wc_uploader.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
    wc_uploader.UploadFileCompleted += FinishProcess;
    wc_uploader.UploadFileAsync(target_file_tmp_name, "STOR", result_file_name);

}
```

Comment: Seems as if you are uploading it to the desired target name directly? What's wrong about that?

Comment: @Fildor need to wait for finishing upload before giving it name. On other side cronjob working and processiing unfinished uploads also

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried some of the answers from Stackoverflow Questions regarding FTP rename? Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13026258/982149 I guess you'd have to start the rename in `FinishProcess` event handler and of course use `target_file_tmp_name` for your STORE command first.

Comment: @Fildor I don't know how to rename after async upload, this is the problem

Comment: @Fildor If I will do it in `FinishProcess` I need to re-connect. This will be time consuming and needless. I need some way that will do it inside 1 connection

Answer (score 2):

Your `FinishProcess` must look like the code below:

```
 private void FinishProcess(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(target_file_tmp_name);
            requestFTP.Proxy = null;
            requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_login, ftp_pass);
            requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
            requestFTP.RenameTo = file_name + ".eps";
            requestFTP.GetResponse();
            ...
```